# How can I get Internet explorer to display this image correctly

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I am trying to get internet explorer to display an image in a table cell correctly. The image will display perfectly fine in chrome, but internet explorer keeps inserting white space above the image. Is there anything else that I can add which will prevent internet explorer from incorrectly displaying the image/table cell? I am trying to get the image to fill up the cell without any white space being the sides of it.

Code that I am using:

```
<p>&#160;</p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 232px;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 292px;">​​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 292px; height: 186px;">​<img src="/Test%20Pics%20Library/map_gif.gif" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; vertical-align: top;"/> </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<p>​</p> 
<br/> 
<br/>
<br/> 
<br/>
```

Internet explorer view:

[image]

Chrome view:

[image]

Comment: Add style display:block; to the image.

Comment: @TanelEero still the same unfortunately. Adding that actually causes the white space to display in chrome as well

Comment: When I copied your code to jsfiddle it shows a number of hidden characters in the table cells and one before the image that creates a row of "text" before the image in IE. Chrome seems to ignore this.

They show up as red dots in the html section in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gfq9odbo/

I would suggest you delete the hidden characters in jsfiddle since they probably don't show up in your editor and then copy the clean code back to your project.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `background-image` of the cell to the image?

Comment: @TanelEero thanks! That did the trick, I had been using sharepoint's built in page editor to make / edit the table, it looks like it may have slipped in some code of its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you  copied this code from somewhere....
there is some special character between `<td></td>`
if you write the code again space will not come or copy this code

```
<p>&#160;</p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 232px;" >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width:292px;"></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width:33.33%;"></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width:33.33%;"></td>

      </tr>
      <tr><td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width:292px;height: 186px;"><img src="SVoice_im.jpeg" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; vertical-align: top;"></td></td>
      <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width:33.33%;"></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width:33.33%;"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<br/> 
<br/>
<br/> 
<br/>
```

Comment: thanks! Pasting it back in did the trick. I had been using sharepoint's built in page editor to make / edit the table, it looks like it may have slipped in some code of its own

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>&#160;</p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 232px;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 292px;">​​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 292px; height: 186px; vertical-align: top; position: relative;">​<img src="/Test%20Pics%20Library/map_gif.gif" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; display: block;"/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 33.33%;">​</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<p>​</p> 
<br/> 
<br/>
<br/> 
<br/>
```

Did you try this?